# Why do I have to convert to ulong inorder to read data from registers?

Tags: c++, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

This is from a program simulating instruction for a MIPS processor.

In the `readWrite` function, why do i have to convert to `u_long` in order to read data from `RdReg1`?

```
class RF
{
    public:
        bitset<32> ReadData1, ReadData2;
        RF()
        {
          Registers.resize(32);
          Registers[0] = bitset<32> (0);
        }

        void ReadWrite(bitset<5> RdReg1, bitset<5> RdReg2, bitset<5> WrtReg, bitset<32> WrtData, bitset<1> WrtEnable)
        {
            // implement the funciton by you.
            ReadData1 = Registers[RdReg1.to_ulong()];//reading data from registers
            ReadData2 = Registers[RdReg2.to_ulong()];
            if(WrtEnable.to_ulong() == 1)//if writeEnable=1 then write data into register
            {
                Registers[WrtReg.to_ulong()] = WrtData;
            }
         }

    void OutputRF()
             {
               ofstream rfout;
                  rfout.open("RFresult.txt",std::ios_base::app);
                  if (rfout.is_open())
                  {
                    rfout<<"A state of RF:"<<endl;
                  for (int j = 0; j<32; j++)
                      {
                        rfout << Registers[j]<<endl;
                      }

                  }
                  else cout<<"Unable to open file";
                  rfout.close();

               }
    private:
            vector<bitset<32> >Registers;

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code takes register numbers as `std::bitset<5>` objects, not an integer type like `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

The `std::bitset<>` class doesn't have implicit conversion to `unsigned long` so you have to use a member function to get an `unsigned long` with the bits of the bitset as its value.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

The class doesn't transparently work as an n-bit integer.  If you want that, you could in theory use an unsigned bitfield in a struct.

---

I think the function is doing this for pedagogical reasons, to remind you that the register number comes from a 5-bit field in the instruction word.  Or else as a way to guarantee that out-of-range values are impossible.  (i.e. only values from 0..31 are possible in a 5-bit bitset.)

**The API implemented by this code is a mess!  The "return values" are returned by assigning to 2 public members of the class**, separate from the register-file array itself**.  Err actually `vector<bitset<32> > Registers`, so the register file is a dynamically allocated and growable/shrinkable container for no apparent reason or benefit vs. `std::array<bitset<32>, 32>`.

I wonder if the code structure is attempting to not only simulate a MIPS pipeline but to internally work like the way the hardware is designed.  i.e. having one function call implement the operation of the register file in a single cycle: reading 2 values for the ID stage and writing 0 or 1 value from the WB stage.  And place the 2 read values in buffers that are part of the register file?  Seems insane vs. returning a `std::pair<uint32_t>`.

I guess combining read+write makes it easier to model the fact that read + write of the same register reads the old value, like an exchange.  Some other logic must  handle bypass forwarding.